# Какая разница между 'git pull' и 'git fetch'?

Tags: git

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, какая разница между `git pull` и `git fetch`? Пользуюсь SourceTree, но недавно решил пересесть на консольный Гит.

Answer (score 23):

`git pull` — это, по сути, команда `git fetch`, после которой сразу же следует `git merge`.

`git fetch` получает изменения с сервера и сохраняет их в каталог `refs/remotes/`.
Это никак не влияет на локальные ветки и текущие изменения. А `git merge` уже вливает все эти изменения в локальную копию.

[Подробнее](http://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/143575842521lohpnj4q).